# How do I tell tmux to automatically resize panes after I kill a pane?

Tags: tmux

When I have three panes of equal width like so:

|------|------|------|

and I kill a pane, my panes might look like this:

|------|-------------|

but I want them to look like this, **automatically**:

|---------|---------|

---

To do this manually, I use `select-layout even-horizontal` with a hotkey.

Maybe there's a way to automatically enter `tmux select-layout even-horizontal` after a pane is killed.

Comment: Have you tried hooks? I haven't tried them myself. Looks like they might work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [i_v_harish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492884/i-v-harish) pointed out in his comment, this is possible from [tmux 2.3+](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES) which introduced hooks on commands.

Panes can close for one of the following reasons.

- Pane ***killed***

  - With `kill-pane` (binded to <kbd><prefix></kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> by default)
- Pane ***exited***

  - The command running in the pane terminates (e.g. if it is a shell and the user types `exit` or presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>)

The following lines can be added to `~/.tmux.conf` to cover both use cases.

```
set-hook -g after-kill-pane 'select-layout even-horizontal'
set-hook -g pane-exited 'select-layout even-horizontal'
```

Hooks are described in the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#HOOKS).

> tmux allows commands to run on various triggers, called hooks. Most tmux commands have an after hook and there are a number of hooks not associated with commands.
>
> A command's after hook is run after it completes, except when the command is run as part of a hook itself. They are named with an ‘after-’ prefix.

There are also a number of different layouts you can select apart from `even-horizontal`.

### even-horizontal

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

### even-vertical

```
+-------------------+
|                   |
+-------------------+
|                   |
+-------------------+
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

### main-horizontal

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|                   |
|                   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

### main-vertical

```
+------+------------+
|      |            |
|      +------------+
|      |            |
|      +------------+
|      |            |
+------+------------+
```

### tiled

```
+---------+---------+
|         |         |
+---------+---------|
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: To activate the hook, one must use the `kill-pane` command, which is not `CTRL+D` by default. The default key is `<prefix> x` and requires a confirmation. One can remove the confirmation by adding `bind x kill-bane` to one's .tmux.conf file.

Comment: @MatthewKleinsmith You are right, but you can also attach a hook for the event when you close the pane with `CTRL+D`. That's a different one called `pane-exited`. I'll add this to my answer as well.